# Nesting CSS Styles or inheritance

Tags: css

I'm pretty new to using CSS beyond applying directly to each element.  I'd like to know how I should be doing this. (simplified from my actual implementation, but relatively the same). Is it possible to inherit styles somehow?

I have 3 div classes defined, each positioning a div in my page. I've left out the css for these, but the style divide my page into 3 sections.

```
div.left{} 
div.center{}
div.right{}
```

Now, when a user selects one of the divs, it's then highlighted, so I have css to highlight it.

```
div.lefthighlighted{}
div.centerhighlighted{}
div.righthighlighted{}
```

I have to now repeat all the styles from div.left{} to div.lefthighlighted{} and add the styles to highlight, and this has to be done for all three div styles I've defined.

OK, I also have a tags within all three of these divs that I want styled different from all other a tags in my application, but they will be the same for the highlightd divs. This is were things get crazy.

I end up with the following for left, center and right.  The worst part of this is that all the a tag styling is the same for left, lefthighlighted, center, centerhighlighted, right and righthighlighted, but I can't figure out how to share all of this.

```
 div.left a:link {}
 div.left a:visited {}
 div.left a:active {}
 div.left a:hover {}
 div.lefthighlighted a:link{}
 div.lefthighlighted a:visited {}
 div.lefthighlighted a:active {}
 div.lefthighlighted a:hover {}
```

Keep in mind, I'm simply putting empty braces here, but in my stylesheet, I've got a bunch of styles defined.  Is there a way to say

```
div.left a:link {
  inherit div.right a:link;
  or 
  use div.right a:link;
 }
```

I'm finding myself copying and pasting all the same styles and only changing the class name or the parent class name.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to define `:active` before `:hover` since in most cases the link will only be activated while the mouse is pointing at it (the exception being when it is focused and the user presses enter … not that you have defined `:focus`).

Comment: It seems I had two issues here, one with defining multiple div styles (9 total) whereas now I only need 4 as per the answer given by @:Quentin.  The problem I had with defining the multiple a tag styles was solved by the answer given by @:Rob W.  I can only mark one answer as correct, so I'm choosing Quentins, but I've upvoted both. Thanks.

Comment: On further thought (see my comment on Quentin's answer), I would have a class for "column" and a class for "highlighted", but use `id="left"` for the one-and-only left, center, and right columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the elements multiple classes.

```
<div class="left highlighted">
```

And then just include the changed properties in the `div.highlighted` rule-set.

Comment: So my a tag styles would then only need to be applied to the left class. This solves my problem of defining muliple lefthighlighted, righthighlighted, etc...

Comment: @Jeff - You could even go for `<div class="highlighted left column">` so the things common to left, center, and right don't have to be repeated; they can be defined once in `div.column { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

You can group styles by using the `,` (commas) as a separator. Eg:

```
div.left a:link, div.right a:link {}

/*Newlines don't matter:*/
div.left a:link,
div.right a:link {}
```

Note that the following does **not** work as "expected":

```
/*Expecting to select all links under div.left or div.right*/
div.left, div.right a:link {/*FAIL*/}
```

Another note about inheritance. Elements inherit styles from their parents. When a new matching selector is encountered, the styles from the parent still apply, unless defined otherwise:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    color: red;
    font-size: 16px;
}
a:hover{
    font-size: 20px; /*font-size changed, while the color is still red.*/
}
```

Comment: This solves my problem of adding the same style defs multiple times.